# Operation time out when attempting to connect to server with SSH after scp started hanging

Tags: linux, ssh, debian

I was transferring a file between two remote machines when the `scp` command stopped at 92%. Now, I'm unable to SSH into my server from my local machine. I do have access via my server host's VNC terminal.

I tried restarting `sshd`, doing a `systemctl reboot`, and shutting down/restarting the server from my host's web panel, but I'm still unable to SSH into the server. I've also checked `/var/log/auth.log` and it hasn't logged anything about the connection timeouts.

I disabled the server firewall completely (iptables) and the output of `systemctl status sshd` shows that it is working and listening on port 22.

Output of `iptables -L`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
```

I have been able to ssh into other servers just fine from my machine. The output of my SSH command with `-vvv` is:

```
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to <server-ip> port 22.
ssh: connect to host <server-ip> port 22: Operation timed out
```

In addition, as mentioned in some other related questions here, I manually started sshd on port 42 with `/usr/sbin/sshd -p 42 -d` and attempted to connect, but the connection still timed out from my local machine and no output was logged to the terminal.

What can I do to troubleshoot?

Comment: Try to SSH to localhost via VNC. This eliminates sshd as the core problem.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding. The VNC terminal asks me for my login/pw and I use the same one that I use for SSH. Are you asking me to run the SSH command within the VNC terminal when I'm already connected?

Comment: Running `ssh user@localhost` within the VNC terminal works.

Comment: Well, now you know sshd on your server should be working correctly. You can do the same on your client machine. You may want to run ssh verbose and edit your question with the output

Answer (score 0):

I talked to the hosting provider live support and they told me that they locked down the IP address due to high network activity thinking it was a DDoS attack. I didn't have access to the email address associated with the account at the time so I didn't get the alert. They lifted the hold, and all is good now.